# Top tag reputation change doesn't clear

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, notifications, activity

Initial reputation card:

[image]

Both `+10` share the same hovering tip:

[image]

After clicking the reputation tab and refreshing the page:

[image]

*Notice the second `+10` is still there while the first `+10` is gone.*

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Stack Overflow, it takes several minutes for the second `+10` to disappear.

Comment: I encounter this somewhat frequently on rpg.se as well.